# Html Quote calculations - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate my html form values.

I have tried the following javascript calculation, but it is not calculating a value into my total field ('total1'). Is there perhaps a problem with the javascript or am I not referencing the form correctly?

```
    <form action="" method="get" id="quote">

<table width="532" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0.5">
  <tr>
    <th width="109" scope="col"><div align="center">Date</div></th>
    <th width="158" scope="col"><div align="center">Half day</div></th>
    <th width="112"><div align="center">Full day</div></th>
    <th width="134"><div align="center">Total for the day</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="date1" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="halfday1" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="fullday1" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="total1" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="date2" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="halfday2" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="fullday2" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="total2" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="date3" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="halfday3" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="fullday3" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input name="total3" type="text" size="15" />
    </div></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>



      function doTotal(quote) {
    var a = (form.halfday1.value != '') ? eval(form.halfday1.value) : 0;
    var b = (form.fullday1.value != '') ? eval(form.fullday1.value) : 0;


    form.total1.value = a + b + c + d + e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZR5LD/

Comment: You aren't calling your 'doTotal' function anywhere

Comment: if you type any javascript code in `form.Amount1` or `form.Amount2` this code is going to be executed when `doTotal` is called. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: @Sebas - I have edited `form.Amount1` and changed it to `form.halfday1`      thank you

Comment: Where are the variables c, d & e created or assigned a value?

Comment: `eval`? no love for `parseInt`? or even `(+form.halfday1.value)`?

Comment: @winterblood - I have deleted c, d, and e. I was supposed to remove them as they were included only in the example which I had

Comment: @user2264587   `eval` was what was used in the example I have.  Would it be better to use `(+form.halfday1.value)` ?

Comment: eval is bad in all but few cases, if you can avoid it, you should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZR5LD/2/

```
function doTotal(form) {
    var a = (+form.halfday1.value);
    var b = (+form.fullday1.value);


    form.total1.value = a + b ;
}
document.getElementById("quote").onclick = function (){doTotal(this)};
```

I don't know what c,d,e were, but `form` was not defined, I assume you meant the form `"quote"`.
also I added the call to `doTotal` in the `onclick` property of the form

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My apologies, c,d,e were not supposed to be there.  Thank you. I appreciate your assistance :)